# URI as resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to specify the Source property of a SoundPlayerAction as resource. I tried the following, but this does not work because a string is not a valid value for the property which expects a Uri.

```
<Window.Resources>
<sys:String x:Key="Test">/SoundFile.wav</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>

<SoundPlayerAction Source="{DynamicResorce Test}" />
```

Is there a way to bring that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution I found was to use a converter:

```
public class UriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is string)) return value;

        var filename = value as string;
        return new Uri(filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then in the xaml file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="MyFile">/SoundFile.wav</sys:String>
    <converter:UriConverter x:Key="UriConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<SoundPlayerAction Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyFile}, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare the XML namesspace as

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=system"
```

and the resources as

```
<sys:Uri x:Key="Test">/SoundFile.wav</sys:Uri>
```

or perhaps as a [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) if the sound file is an assembly resource:

```
<sys:Uri x:Key="Test">pack://application:,,,/SoundFile.wav</sys:Uri>
```

Comment: interesting, I tried that but intellisense did not suggest the Uri type, thats why I ended up aksing the question. but it seems to work, thanks

Comment: Perhaps because you had used the `mscorlib` assembly instead of `system`.

Comment: Actually that did not really work. There was neither a compiler nor runtime error, but the sound did not play. I ended up using a converter.

Comment: In case the sound file is an assembly resource, you may need to specify a full [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx), or to be more precise, a [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly).